# Can you search Opportunity Contact Roles in the Search Menu?

Tags: search, opportunitycontactrole

[image]

This brings up the Contact he is associated with and I know you can get to Contact Roles there, but my client wants to be able to find the Opportunities directly and go into them without any extra clicks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this can't work with the global search out of the box. You can't search for elements in related lists and bring up their parent/master as a match.

You could create a custom text field on opportunity and create a scheduled job (unfortunately triggers are not supported), which concatenates the contact names into that field. You need the carefully decide between text (255) and long text (128000). Both have pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think they want me to add custom code for a small amount of functionality.  They decided they are better off splitting them into lookup fields on the Opportunity instead.

Comment: not so simple to get OCR names onto the Oppo as triggers can't be written on OCR; requires scheduled job

Comment: @crop1645 did you try an opportunity trigger? I heard that for other untriggerable entities it might bubble up to the parent (e.g. changes of OpportunityLineItemSchedule should let an opportunity trigger fire) but probably you're right here.

Comment: @UweHeim - there are several posts on this topic such as these -https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrdvAAC, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/47191/2602; it is true that a change in OpportunityLineItem triggers parent Oppo change (at least if amount has changed because Opportunity.amount is an implicit RSF field)

Comment: @crop1645 thanks for clarification. Updated the answer accordingly.